# What is SSZ SimpleSerialize and why was it developed?

Tags: merkleization, eth-2.0, ssz, serialization

We were looking at the latest [spec](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/5d8c31cfb17feff2edffbba1830437569611bc42/specs/simple-serialize.md) and it didn't have much background information or explanation on what SSZ is trying to achieve. What are the key goals of SSZ?

Examples of its serialization and Merkleization advantages would be very helpful as this may be a canonical question.

Comment: Read this a while ago, but didn't actually digest it at the time. (And still haven't!) Possibly of use from "Why a New Serialization Format? Why Not Protobuf, JSON, or Others?" onward... -> https://rauljordan.com/2019/07/02/go-lessons-from-writing-a-serialization-library-for-ethereum.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SimpleSerialize (SSZ) is the canonical serialization format used in Eth2. The [SSZ specification](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/ssz/simple-serialize.md) instructs the reader on how to perform two distinct tasks:

1. **Encoding/Decoding**: how to encode Eth2 data structures (e.g., a [`BeaconBlock`](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#beaconblock) or a [`BeaconState`](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#beaconstate)) as strings of bytes that can be sent over the network or stored in a database.
2. **Merkleization**: how to find the hash of a given data structure (technically it's a [Merkle root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), not a normal "hash").

For each I will state the goals (or my understanding of them) and also an example for each of these tasks.

### 1. Encoding/Decoding

As far as I know, there was never a canonical statement of the goals of SSZ. However, I think it's fair to say that these are some of the goals:

- **Simple**: this format was initially defined by Vitalik Buterin who wanted a format that's simpler than RLP (the Eth1 encoding scheme).
- **Bijective**: for some instance of a type there should be *only one* SSZ representation of that instance; you should never be able to have different bytes represent the same `BeaconBlock`. With this property, the SSZ encoding forms an "identity" for that instance.
- **Compact**: SSZ bytes need to be sent over the network, so they should be compact (without jeopardizing simplicity).
- **Merkle-first**: compatible by design with Merkle-proof schemes that will come into effect in later phases of Eth2.
- **Cheap to traverse**: the first version of SSZ did not include the "offsets" scheme, however Peter Szilagyi (Geth) suggested including the offsets which would make it cheap to traverse through the fields of the serialized structure. This is great for constrained environments (e.g., the EVM) which may want to read a single field of the struct without decoding the entire thing.

#### Encoding/Decoding Example

I will provide a simple example and also recommend the reader to [@protolambda's SSZ encoding diagram](https://github.com/protolambda/eth2-docs#ssz-encoding).

Lets assume this imaginary data structure since none of the structures in the Eth2 spec are great for this example:

```py
class Example
    id: uint64,
    bytes: List[uint8, 64]
    next: uint64
```

The `Example` has two 64-bit integer fields (`id` and `next`) and a `bytes` field that can hold 0-64 bytes. Lets instantiate it:

```
my_example = Example(id=42, bytes=List[0, 1, 2], next=43)
```

Now, lets look at the output of `serialize(my_example)`:

```
# serialize(my_example)
#
# Note: this is a single byte-array split over four lines for readability.
[
  42, 0, 0, 0,  # The little-endian encoding of `id`, 42.
  12, 0, 0, 0,  # The "offset" that indicates where the variable-length value of `bytes` starts (little-endian 12).
  43, 0, 0, 0,  # The little-endian encoding of `next`, 43.
  0, 1, 2       # The value of the `bytes` field.
]
```

As we can see, fields are encoded in the order that they are defined. ["Fixed-size"](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/ssz/simple-serialize.md#variable-size-and-fixed-size) items are simply serialized right into the buffer, whilst ["variable-sized"](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.11.1/ssz/simple-serialize.md#variable-size-and-fixed-size) items are first serialized as an "offset" that points to the start of the actual *value* of the the item. The actual *values* (not offsets) of variable-size items are appended *after* all the fixed-size items and offsets have been appended.

### 2. Merklization

Eth2 does not just use a simple SHA256 hash of encoding of a block to identify it (e.g., `sha256(serialize(block))`. Instead, *all* hashes in Eth2 are Merkle-roots.

The decision to use Merkle-roots for all hashes was made so that light clients and execution environments can use Merkle-proofs to learn about parts of the Eth2 state. For example, if a light client has a trusted 32-byte hash of some block root, I can make a succinct, cryptographic proof to that light client that validator `n` has a balance of `x`.

However, the decision to use Merkle-roots as the canonical hash has a significant computational overhead. The syncing bottle-neck in Lighthouse (the client I work on) is performing these Merkle-hashes. Some of these routines take tens of milliseconds when a simple `sha256(serialize(block))` would take microseconds (that's millions of times slower).

So, I would say the goal of the Merkleization scheme is to ensure that constrained environments (light clients, execution environments, eth1, etc.) can have access to light-weight proofs which they can use to make important decisions.

#### Merklization Example

Let's use the previous `Example` type and also the `my_example` instantiation. Again, I suggest a diagram by @protolambda: [SSZ hash-tree-root and merklization](https://github.com/protolambda/eth2-docs#ssz-hash-tree-root-and-merkleization).

To aid in the example, we define `hash_concat(a, b)` which returns the SHA256 hash of the concatenation of `a` and `b`. E.g., `hash_concat([1], [2]) == hash([1, 2])`.

First, we determine the leaves of the `Example` Merkle tree:

```
# id: little-endian 42, right-0-padded to 32 bytes.
leaf_0 = [42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# bytes: when a list is hashed, you first hash the list values (right-0-padded to the next multiple of 32) along with the little-endian encoding of the list length (aka.,  "mixing in the length").
leaf_1 = hash_concat(
  [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [3, 0, 0, 0]
)

# id: little-endian 43, right-0-padded to 32 bytes.
leaf_2 = [43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now, we hash the leaves into the middle-layer of the Merkle tree:

```
# Hash the concatenation of `id` and `bytes`.
node_1 = hash_concat(leaf_0, leaf_1);

# Hash the concatentation of `next` and a "zero leaf" (32 zero-bytes), since there is no fourth element.
node_2 = hash_concat(leaf_2, [0; 32])
```

Finally, we can find the root of this Merkle tree with `root = hash_concat(node_1, node_2)`.

Ultimately, we have produced a nested Merkle tree that looks like this:

```
             root
               |
       -----------------
      /                  \
 node_1                node_2
    |                     |
  ------             -----------
 /      \           /           \
id  bytes_root    next       ZERO_LEAF
         |
      -------
     /       \
  bytes   len(bytes)
```

Comment: regarding leaf_1, is it: leaf_1 = hash_concat(
  hash([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
  [3, 0, 0, 0]
)?

Comment: how come The little-endian encoding of 42, is 42,0,0,0? Also how do one know which is fixed value and offset?

Comment: How also are the fields name preserved when serialized such that you have them back upon deserialization?

Comment: Yes, how come the little endian encoding of uint64 42 and 43 are encoded into 4 bytes and not 8? Is offset always a uint32?